# RXjS Pipeable Operator: "Property does not exist"

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm coming back to an Angular project after a long while away, and I'm updating Angular (and RxJS) to version 6. One of the many errors being thrown relate (I assume) to pipeable operators, which were new in RxJS 6. Here's an example of one:

`src/app/member-view/member-view.service.ts(126,13): error TS2339: Property 'monthOne' does not exist on type 'any[]'.`

Here's the code that throws it:

```py
let results = this.db.list(`renown/${uid}/${this.years[0]}/${this.months[0]}/total`)
.pipe(switchMap(total => {
    let joinedObservables: any[] = []
    joinedObservables.push(this.db
        .object(`renown/${uid}/${this.years[0]}/${this.months[0]}/total`)
        .pipe(tap(value => {
            if (value.$value !== null) {
                total.monthOne = value.$value
```

This error did not exist until the operator `switchMap` was moved to within the `.pipe()`, which is required as of RxJS 6. Is this a typing issue or a syntax error?

Comment: Apparently the `$value` atribute of the result of `this.db.object(...)` is an array. Maybe you want to use `value.$value[0]`...

Comment: total is actually an int. I'm realizing that I'm assigning a property to total here, the assigning a value to that. Can I not assign a property this way anymore?

Comment: Yeah, I updated my comment right after adding it (I've noticed I was referring to the wrong part of the code). Based on my updated comment above, it worth `console.log(value.$value)`

Comment: It's just javascript, you can do whatever you want most of the time. Creating a property on `total` is not an issue (I find it particularly confusing in the long term).

Comment: Thing is, if I remove the `.pipe(switchMap...)` there's no error. Except it doesn't recognize `switchMap` anymore because with RxJS you have to pipe operators now. And the code won't compile, so I can't log in the console.

Comment: try "cast" total as switchMap((total:any)=>{...}) but make sure that total is an object and not an array

Comment: @Eliseo that worked. Would you be able to put that into an answer and explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You should type your data all the way. Since you haven't typed your data, `this.db.list` apparently gives you `any[]`, since it's not typed. So type your data all the way by for example using interfaces, here I am using `MyType1>` and `MyType2>`:

```ts
let results = this.db.list<MyType1>(`renown/${uid}/${this.years[0]}/${this.months[0]}/total`)
.pipe(switchMap((total: MyType1) => {
    let joinedObservables: MyType[] = []
    joinedObservables.push(this.db
        .object<MyType2>(`renown/${uid}/${this.years[0]}/${this.months[0]}/total`)
        .pipe(tap((value: MyType2) => {
            if (value.$value !== null) {
                total.monthOne = value.$value
```